# How do you specifically order ggplot2 x axis instead of alphabetical order?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-faq

I'm trying to make a `heatmap` using `ggplot2` using the `geom_tiles` function
here is my code below:

```
p<-ggplot(data,aes(Treatment,organisms))+geom_tile(aes(fill=S))+
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "black",high = "red") + 
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  theme(legend.position = "right", 
    axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = base_size, angle = 90, hjust = 0, colour = "black"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = base_size, hjust = 1, colour = "black")).
```

data is my data.csv file
my X axis is types of Treatment
my Y axis is types of organisms

I'm not too familiar with commands and programming and I'm relatively new at this. I just want to be able to specify the order of the labels on the x axis. In this case, I'm trying to specify the order of "Treatment". By default, it orders alphabetically. How do I override this/keep the data in the same order as in my original csv file?

I've tried this command

```
scale_x_discrete(limits=c("Y","X","Z"))
```

where x, y and z are my treatment condition order. It however doesn't work very well, and give me missing heat boxes.

Comment: Voting to reopen since the linked dup is about reordering by frequency, whereas this question is about imposing an arbitrary order, and is a useful dup target for that case.

Answer (score 168, accepted):

It is a little difficult to answer your specific question without a full, reproducible example. However something like this should work:

```
#Turn your 'treatment' column into a character vector
data$Treatment <- as.character(data$Treatment)
#Then turn it back into a factor with the levels in the correct order
data$Treatment <- factor(data$Treatment, levels=unique(data$Treatment))
```

In this example, the order of the factor will be the same as in the `data.csv` file.

If you prefer a different order, you can order them by hand:

```
data$Treatment <- factor(data$Treatment, levels=c("Y", "X", "Z"))
```

However this is dangerous if you have a lot of levels: if you get any of them wrong, that will cause problems.

Comment: Have to wonder why this is even necessary.  Why are the axes reordered by ggplot in the first place?  Seems dangerous if someone isn't aware this is going to happen.

Comment: I just ran into this problem myself making a [heatmap with qplot](http://martinsbioblogg.wordpress.com/2013/03/21/using-r-correlation-heatmap-with-ggplot2/) and automatically applied variable names. Should it be reported?

Comment: @DirkCalloway, this behavior makes sense if you think about how factors work in R. A factor is a vector of integers, each of which is associated with a character 'label'. When you create a factor by reading a column of character values in a text file (e.g. `.csv`), R assigns the integer values in alphabetical order rather than in the order they appear in the file. You can argue whether that makes sense, but `ggplot2` then does the logical thing, which is to display the factor levels in order of their integer values. Your complaint is with `read.table`, not `ggplot2`.

Answer (score 100):

One can also simply factorise within the `aes()` call directly. I am not sure why setting the limits doesn't work for you - I assume you get NA's because you might have typos in your level vector.

The below is certainly not much different than [user Drew Steen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12783167/7941188), but with the important difference of not changing the original data frame.

```r
library(ggplot2)
## this vector might be useful for other plots/analyses
level_order <- c('virginica', 'versicolor', 'setosa') 

p <- ggplot(iris)
p + geom_bar(aes(x = factor(Species, level = level_order)))
```

[image]

```r
## or directly in the aes() call without a pre-created vector:
p + geom_bar(aes(x = factor(Species, level = c('virginica', 'versicolor', 'setosa')))) 
## plot identical to the above - not shown
```

```r
## or use your vector as limits in scale_x_discrete
p + geom_bar(aes(x = Species)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = level_order)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I prefer using 

```
level_order <- c('virginica', 'versicolor', 'setosa')
ggplot(iris, aes(x =Species, y = Petal.Width)) + geom_col() + scale_x_discrete(limits = level_order)
```

Comment: @Ceres this is of course also a great option. Thanks for sharing. as the question is closed you won't be able to add your suggestion as an answer, therefore I have added it to mine.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the very same problem with data being reordered alphabetically. Solution  with scale_x_discrete worked for me perfectly:

```
scale_x_discrete(c('B', 'A', 'C'))
#where A, B and C are labels.
```

Comment: In the case that the plot has ```facet_wrap```,```scale_x_discrete(c('B', 'A', 'C'))``` would not work unless you add the ```limit``` argument, as in ```scale_x_discrete(limit = c('B', 'A', 'C'))```.