# Change month order using R and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I'm having a pretty big problem. I'm trying to plot animal density (using two methods) against months.

When I plot one of the two methods, the months go out of order and I can't seem to get them to work.

In the end I want to have each of the two methods (camera.estimations and scat.estimations) on the same plot, with SD of each included and months in the right order. Any pointers from you lovely R folk would be awesome!

Here's my data:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AjSTnjcF57_IdEhUXzFyQmtZaG5NXzdzTXZkbFdweXc&usp=sharing

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow! People are generally much more happy to help if you post a [**minimal, reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) together with the code you already have tried. Also have a look at [a nice **checklist for questions** on SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Thanks.

Comment: You probably have months sorted in alphabetical order. A kick-fix is to use numbers instead. If you want something else, you should rephrase your question and show what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this post to help structure my ggplots before

[How do you specifically order ggplot2 x axis instead of alphabetical order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774210/how-do-you-specifically-order-ggplot2-x-axis-instead-of-alphabetical-order)

Manually setting the order of factors works but can be annoying, but is the best answer I have for you :)
without more information hope it helps!