# Solving ggplot sorting/combining of variable names without enforcing fixed order

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is related to [this question about ggplot changing the order of variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774210/how-do-you-specifically-order-ggplot2-x-axis-instead-of-alphabetical-order). The answer given there, which manually enforces a bijective reordering of factor levels, does not solve the problem in general. An example is the output of `melt(matcor(data.A,data.B)$XYcor)`, which repeats the rows twice:

```
data.A <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(c(25)),nrow=5,ncol=5))
data.B <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(c(25)),nrow=5,ncol=5))

library(ggplot)
library(CCA)
qplot(x=Var1, y=Var2, data=melt(matcor(data.A,data.B)$XYcor), fill=value, geom="tile")
```

The idea behind this plot is to show the cross-correlation between two multivariate sets, as `img.matcor` does:

```
img.matcor(matcor(data.A,data.B))
```

[image: XYcor plot]

In this picture, the upper-left and lower-right quadrants are the autocorrelation matrices of `data.A` and `data.B`, while the other quadrants are flipped versions of the cross-correlation matrix. Reordering the data as ggplot2 does destroys this relationship. (On the other hand, ggplot makes this look *way* better.)

Calling `melt` with `factor.levels=FALSE` does not fix this, unfortunately, and in the first place, `melt` orders the columns properly. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you get wrong plot with `qplot()` at least for sample data because you have the same column names in `data.A` and `data.B` and then in `qplot()` you get only part of actual correlations. If you change column names for one of data frames then `qplot()` looks more similar to `img.matcor()`. Only autocorrelation matrices now are one left bottom and right upper parts.

```
set.seed(1)
data.A <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(c(25)),nrow=5,ncol=5))
names(data.A)<-c("A1","A2","A3","A4","A5")
data.B <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(c(25)),nrow=5,ncol=5))
qplot(x=Var1, y=Var2, data=melt(matcor(data.A,data.B)$XYcor), 
              fill=value, geom="tile")
```

[image]

Comment: That's good to know. Unfortunately it ruins the convenient syntax of `data.table` stuff like `matcor(mydata[Class==0,mycols,with=FALSE],                             mydata[Class!=0,mycols,with=FALSE])`

Comment: I see your point but I'm not sure that you can use use the same column names because you get the same discrete names that are used for x and y axis and those data are overlaid on the plot in the same position.