# r ggplot x axis tick marks order

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I've seen several questions about the order of x axis marks but still none of them could solve my problem.
I'm trying to do a density plot which shows the distribution of people by percentile within each score given like this

```
library(dplyr); library(ggplot2); library(ggtheme)
ggplot(KA,aes(x=percentile,group=kscore,color=kscore))+
  xlab('Percentil')+ ylab('Frecuencia')+ theme_tufte()+ ggtitle("Prospectos")+
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Greens")+geom_density(size=3)
```

but the x axis mark gets ordered like 1,10,100,11,12,..,2,20,21,..,99 instead of just 1,2,3,..,100 which is my desired output
[image]

I fear this affects the whole plot not just the labels

Comment: Your x variable is a factor. You probably want it to be numeric. `KA$percentile = as.numeric(as.character(KA$percentile))`.

Comment: adding a `dput(head(KA))` would help confirm this

Comment: ...but when your sorting is clearly alphabetical "1, 10, 100, 11, 12, ..., 2", confirmation is hardly necessary.

Comment: And with 100 levels `dput(droplevels(head(KA)))` would be better.

Comment: Because the x axis is ordered alphabetically you can check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774210/how-do-you-specifically-order-ggplot2-x-axis-instead-of-alphabetical-order

Comment: Tried all suggestions thanks everyone! 
@Gregor 's worked better the other suggestions didn't solve the alphabetical order issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll turn my comment to an answer so this can be marked resolved:

Your x variable is (almost certainly) a factor. You probably want it to be numeric.

```
KA$percentile = as.numeric(as.character(KA$percentile))
```

When you're seeing weird stuff, it's good to check on your data. Running `str(KA)` is a good way to see what's there. If you just want to see classes, `sapply(KA, class)` is a nice summary.

And it's a common R quirk that if you're converting from factor to numeric, go by way of character or you risk ending up with just the level numbers:

```
year_fac = factor(1998:2002)
as.numeric(year_fac) # not so good
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
as.numeric(as.character(year_fac)) # what you want
# [1] 1998 1999 2000 2001 2002
```