# why the order of factor does not change

Tags: r

I am trying to make the order from small to big when I plot a figure .

This is the data

```
df <- structure(list(label = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c(" data1", " data10", " data15", 
" data20", " data5", " data8"), class = "factor"), variable = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("boys", 
"girls"), class = "factor"), N = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("1", "10", "15", 
"20", "5", "8"), class = "factor"), value = c(93987048.3466667, 
54815262.22, 2050259639.66667, 2154175512.5, 3101847435.66667, 
2881192196, 6625604632, 3739286226.5, 270853386.15, 430516498, 
675222758.633333, 717219589.4), sd = c(129474855.769856, 48756976.8630242, 
777498079.458271, 301433971.74375, 1109031077.05936, 45164769.8052193, 
1060915464.90521, 1147931493.65351, 239740705.411582, 38453433.9415797, 
123930253.814345, 112112765.581137), se = c(74752342.8320143, 
34476388.97, 448888725.46965, 213146005.5, 640299390.87988, 31936315, 
612519829.250459, 811710143.5, 138414360.805088, 27190683.9, 
71551165.4004505, 79275696.8), ci = c(321633371.941334, 438064056.816815, 
1931412299.99575, 2708276784.58082, 2754985922.02623, 405789356.908967, 
2635460115.35016, 10313755269.7407, 595548927.354538, 345490396.550009, 
307859817.127003, 1007293234.14371)), .Names = c("label", "variable", 
"N", "value", "sd", "se", "ci"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

based on this answer, I should be able to convert the label to character and then factor and then sort it. [How do you specifically order ggplot2 x axis instead of alphabetical order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774210/how-do-you-specifically-order-ggplot2-x-axis-instead-of-alphabetical-order)

So I did like this

```
df$N <- as.character(df$N)
#Then turn it back into an ordered factor
df$N <- factor(df$N, levels=unique(df$N))
```

If I `str` the df, I can see that it change the character to factor but the level does not change

I even tried to manually change the level

```
df$N <- factor(df$N, levels=c("1","5","8","10","15","20"))
```

but I am still unable to change the order in plot

so if i do `df[order(df$N),]`  nothing happens

```
library(ggplot2)
pd <- position_dodge(0.1) 
ggplot(df, aes(x=N, y=value, colour=variable)) + 
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value-se, ymax=value+se), width=.1, position=pd) +
    geom_line(position=pd) +
    geom_point(position=pd)
```

Comment: `df$N <- factor(df$N, levels=c("1","5","8","10","15","20"))` worked for me.  The x-axis of the plot is labeled (in order): 1, 5, 8, 10, 15, 20.

Comment: Setting the levels manually worked for me as well.

Comment: @Nathan Werth what could be the problem that it does not work for me? which version of R are you using or package please?

Comment: I ran the statement immediately after creating the data from your example.  If you ran a couple things between the two while experimenting, that could've affected the result.

Comment: @Nathan Werth it is very strange !!! you are right . Thanks for the point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `N` to character then to numeric and sort it.

```
# Sort N (Using OPs data)   
df$N2 <- factor(df$N, levels = sort(unique(as.numeric(as.character(df$N)))))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(N2, value, colour = variable)) + 
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = value - se, ymax = value + se), 
                  width = 0.1, position = pd) +
    geom_line(position = pd) +
    geom_point(position = pd)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, would you please tell why you convert it like that?? and why as a new label and not copy it on its own?

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that there's a distinction between the problem you're proposing, and the question you linked to. In the question linked, they were using X, Y, and Z as representations of groups. They wanted those groups ordered in a specific way.

Here, you are using numbers, and you want them in ascending order. You shouldn't categorize them as `factor`. Rather, they should be categorized as `numeric`.

You may still load your `numeric` data in as a factor, but you'll need to convert it to `character` first, and then `numeric`.

```
df$N <- as.numeric(as.character(df$N))

pd <- position_dodge(0.1) 
ggplot(df, aes(x=N, y=value, colour=variable)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value-se, ymax=value+se), width=.1, position=pd) +
  geom_line(position=pd) +
  geom_point(position=pd)
```

[image]

Comment: i cannot like your answer because of my rep. but thanks