# Is there a way to use vectors to determine the order of x-axis labels and plot colours when using facet_wrap in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I would like to make 3 plots using facet_wrap, where I could set the order of the x-axis based on `myOrder`, and the colours based on `myColours`.
I have the following `data.frame`:

```
Cell <- c("AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", 
      "AAA", "ABB", "ABB", "ABB", "ABB", "ABB", "ABB", "ABB", "ABB", 
      "ABB", "ABB", "ACB", "ACB", "ACB", "ACB", "ACB", "ACB", "ACB", 
      "ACB", "ACB", "ACB", "BAA", "BAA", "BAA", "BAA", "BAA", "BAA", 
      "BAA", "BAA", "BAA", "BAA", "BCA", "BCA", "BCA", "BCA", "BCA", 
      "BCA", "BCA", "BCA", "BCA", "BCA", "BCC", "BCC", "BCC", "BCC", 
      "BCC", "BCC", "BCC", "BCC", "BCC", "BCC", "CAA", "CAA", "CAA", 
      "CAA", "CAA", "CAA", "CAA", "CAA", "CAA", "CAA", "CCC", "CCC", 
      "CCC", "CCC", "CCC", "CCC", "CCC", "CCC", "CCC", "CCC", "CBA", 
      "CBA", "CBA", "CBA", "CBA", "CBA", "CBA", "CBA", "CBA", "CBA")
Mean <- c(8, 11, 37, 3, 30, 8, 38, 50, 9, 31, 27, 41, 16, 
      29, 4, 29, 28, 22, 48, 36, 13, 46, 21, 41, 38, 21, 
      26, 27, 49, 4, 38, 44, 49, 48, 32, 3, 6, 25, 33, 
      9, 9, 6, 8, 43, 21, 44, 41, 49, 32, 35, 40, 2, 41, 
      34, 22, 12, 0, 21, 39, 30, 49, 26, 26, 39, 4, 13, 
      18, 12, 9, 29, 24, 40, 38, 17, 40, 13, 30, 8, 9, 
      11, 40, 19, 46, 6, 49, 38, 16, 1, 34, 22)
Type <- c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
      "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
      "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
      "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
      "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
      "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
      "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3")
TesT <- data.frame(Cell,Mean, Type)
```

I have been trying to plot these data using ggplot with the following code:

```
myOrder <- c("AAA", "ACB", "ABB", "BCA", "BAA", "BCC", "CBA", "CAA", "CCC")
myColours <- c("red", "blue", "green", "red", "blue", "green", rep("grey", 3))

ggplot(TesT, aes(x = Cell, y = Mean, fill = Cell)) + 
  theme_bw() +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar") +
  geom_boxplot(colour = "black") +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = myOrder, labels = myOrder) +
  scale_fill_manual(limits = myOrder, values = myColours) + 
  facet_wrap(~Type, scales = "free_x") +
  scale_shape()
```

This is what I get:

[image]

My problem is that I do not manage to get the x-axis in the correct order (the order in `myOrder`).
The only way in which I managed to do this was by changing **breaks** to **limits**  (`scale_x_discrete(limits = myOrder, labels = myOrder)`). However, when I do this I get all the possible x categories in all the plots:
 [image]

I have spent quite some time looking for an answer in here and in google but nothing seems to solve my problem. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: @camille I don't think this is a duplicate. Even though the solution is the same, I think that as a problem it is a bit different, as I am concerned with the order in the axis and not in the legend. As an explicitly different question it can be useful for others facing the same problem in a similar context (but maybe this is just my newbie perspective...)

Comment: That's fair to point out that you're asking about legend order vs axis label order, but you ask also about the order of the colors, which by default will be the same as the order in the legend. Either way, there are definitely a lot of posts already on ordering an axis; [here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3253641/5325862) with 5 answers, and [here's another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12774210/5325862)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `TesT$Cell` as a factor, and specify the order of the levels.

```
TesT$Cell <- factor(TesT$Cell, levels=myOrder)
```

The plotting code doesn't need to change.

[image]