# ggplot2 graphic order by grouped variable instead of in alphabetical order

Tags: r, r-factor

I have a large dataframe with information about newspapers in certain regions ("cantons") in Switzerland. A minimum, reproducible example may look like this:

```
dataframe <- data.frame(canton=c("AG","AG","BE","LU","ZH","ZH"),
                        canton_id=c(19,19,2,3,1,1),
                        newspaper=c("AZ","ZOF","BZ","NLZ","AVU","LB"),
                        minimum=c("1999-12-03","2000-10-03","1998-12-03","1998-01-03","2011-04-03","2002-04-03"),
                        maximum=c("2009-09-29","2018-11-27","2018-11-27","2017-02-14","2018-11-27","2018-11-27"))
```

I need to plot a graphic with ggplot2 that should look similar to this one (please ignore the black points and consider this graphic beeing much bigger than the one resulting of the reproducible example):
[image]

Now, what have I already done? The closest I got was with the following code:

```
ggplot(dataframe) + geom_segment(aes(x=minimum, xend=maximum, y=newspaper, yend=newspaper, size = 1, color = canton))
```

Biggest Concern about my "solution": If a canton has more than one newspaper, I need them grouped by this canton, not in an alphabetical order. Do I need to work with factors?

I have already consulted the following questions:

[How do you specifically order ggplot2 x axis instead of alphabetical order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774210/how-do-you-specifically-order-ggplot2-x-axis-instead-of-alphabetical-order)

[Order discrete x scale by frequency/value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253641/order-discrete-x-scale-by-frequency-value)

If you need any further information, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use a `facet_grid()` approach to group by canton like this (I have used the data you shared):

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
ggplot(dataframe) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x=minimum, xend=maximum, y=newspaper,
                   yend=newspaper, size = 1, color = canton),show.legend = F)+
  facet_grid(canton~.,scales='free')+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(strip.background = element_blank())
```

Output:

[image]