# Plotting dummy variables with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I actually need help building on this question:
[ggplot2 graphic order by grouped variable instead of in alphabetical order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64293655/ggplot2-graphic-order-by-grouped-variable-instead-of-in-alphabetical-order/64486430#64486430).
I need to produce a similar graph and I actually have a problem with the black points. I have data where column names are dates and rows are filled with 0 or 1 and I need to plot the point if the value is 1. To reproduce, here is a small sample (in my dataset, there is over 300 columns):

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3),
                 "26April1970"=c(0,0,1),
                 "14August1970"=c(0,1,0))
```

I need to plot the dates on the x axis, match the id to the canton and show the points where the value is 1.
Could anyone help?

Comment: I don't think that question you link is at all related to your question. To use `ggplot` effectively you need to put your data in a long format. (That is, you want dates on the x-axis? Then you need one column with dates in it - not dates as the names of many columns.). See [this FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2185252/903061) about reshaping data from wide to long. Get your data in long format, then convert your dates to actual `Date` class objects, and building the plot will be easy.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
plot_data = df %>% 
  ## put data in long format
  pivot_longer(-id, names_to = "colname") %>%
  ## keep only 1s
  filter(value == 1) %>%
  ## convert dates to Date class
  mutate(date = as.Date(colname, format = "%d%B%Y"))
plot_data
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#      id colname      value date      
#   <dbl> <chr>        <dbl> <date>    
# 1     2 14August1970     1 1970-08-14
# 2     3 26April1970      1 1970-04-26


## plot
ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = date, y = factor(id))) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

---

Using this data:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3),
                 "26April1970"=c(0,0,1),
                 "14August1970"=c(0,1,0), check.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: That sounds like a new question... I don't think I can provide anything useful without sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Data
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3),
                 "26April1970"=c(0,0,1),
                 "14August1970"=c(0,1,0))
#Code
df %>% pivot_longer(-id) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=name,y=factor(value)))+
  geom_point(aes(color=factor(value)))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c('transparent','black'))+
  theme(legend.position = 'none')+xlab('Date')+ylab('value')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @RRR Understood you have 20 variables so made this change `scale_color_manual(values=c('transparent',rep('black',19)))`

Comment: @RRR Let me know how that goes! Also it looks like you have a different data to that posted!

Comment: @RRR It is your data, could you please use `dput(yourdata)` and paste the output in the question with the editing option?

Comment: Why are you map anything to `color`? OP wants all points black, so delete `scale_color_manual`, delete `color = factor(value)`, and put `color  = "black"` in the `geom_point` layer outside of `aes()`.