# ggplot2: unable to sort x axis based on custom ordering of factor variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, x-axis

I am trying to create a bar plot with custom ordering of x axis (factor variable). After searching around for about 3 hours, I think I should ask for help directly.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)
library(extrafont) #extrafont::font_import()
library(scales)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggrepel)
get_wraper <- function(width) {
  function(x) {
    lapply(strwrap(x, width = width, simplify = FALSE), paste, collapse="\n")
  }
}
graph_object <- function(d, font="Verdana", facet = FALSE, title = "", repel = FALSE, repel_force = 0.3)
{
  d1 <- d
  #relevel factor variable for ggplot2
  p <- ggplot(data = d1, aes(x = paste0(tag), y=percentage, fill=variant2, order = -as.numeric(variant2))) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", color = "black", width = 0.5)
  if(repel == TRUE)
  {
    p <- p + geom_text_repel(data=d1, aes(label = paste0(variant, "\n(", frequency, ")"), y = percentage), size=2.8, position = position_stack(vjust = .5), colour = "black", force = repel_force, max.iter = 10, family=font)
  }else
  {
    p <- p + geom_text(data=d1, aes(label = paste0(variant, "\n(", frequency, ")"), y = percentage), size=2.8, position = position_stack(vjust = .5), colour = "black", family=font) 
  }
  p <- p +  scale_x_discrete(labels = get_wraper(5)) +
    scale_fill_grey(start = 0.5, end = 0.8)+
    scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())+
    theme_bw()+
    theme(legend.position = "none") +
    theme(text=element_text(family=font, colour = "black"), panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank() ,panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(), panel.grid.major.y = element_blank())+
    theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank())+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour="black"), axis.text.y = element_text(colour="black"))
  if(facet == TRUE)
  {
    p <- p + facet_wrap(~ study, ncol = 1)
  }
  p
}
tag = c("una", "una", "una", "una", "na", "na", "na", "na", "pikin", "pikin", "pikin", "pikin", "dey", "dey", "dey", "dey", "wey", "wey", "wey", "wey")
variant = c("other", "una", "other", "una", "other", "na", "other", "na", "other", "pikin(s)", "other", "pikin(s)", "other", "dey", "other", "dey", "other", "wey", "other", "wey")
study= c("Present Study", "Present Study", "Deuber and Hinrichs (2007)", "Deuber and Hinrichs (2007)", "Present Study", "Present Study", "Deuber and Hinrichs (2007)", "Deuber and Hinrichs (2007)", "Present Study", "Present Study", "Deuber and Hinrichs (2007)", "Deuber and Hinrichs (2007)", "Present Study", "Present Study", "Deuber and Hinrichs (2007)", "Deuber and Hinrichs (2007)", "Present Study", "Present Study", "Deuber and Hinrichs (2007)", "Deuber and Hinrichs (2007)")
variant2= c("other", "main", "other", "main", "other", "main", "other", "main", "other", "main", "other", "main", "other", "main", "other", "main", "other", "main", "other", "main")
frequency= c(55, 1094, 4, 746, 188, 8161, 2, 1598, 6, 711, 7, 101, 1753, 11878, 50, 2495, 311, 7410, 23, 1546)
percentage= c(0.047867711, 0.952132289, 0.005333333, 0.994666667, 0.022517667, 0.977482333, 0.00125, 0.99875, 0.008368201, 0.991631799, 0.064814815, 0.935185185, 0.128603918, 0.871396082, 0.019646365, 0.980353635, 0.040279757, 0.959720243, 0.014659018, 0.985340982)
df = cbind.data.frame(tag, variant, study, variant2, frequency, percentage)
df$tag <- as.character(df$tag)
df$tag <- factor(x=df$tag, levels=c("una", "na", "pikin", "dey", "wey"), ordered=T)
df <- df[order(df$tag),]
df
p1 <- graph_object(df, facet = TRUE)
plot(p1)
```

As the code shows I am creating a faceted bar plot with the reproduceable example data (`df`). The x-axis should be ordered in the way specified in `factor(df$tag, levels(...))` function. However, the end result is always alphabetically ordered x axis. The option `ordered=T` in `factor` does not do anything as well. I have also tried with `forcats::fct_relevel` without success. Moreover, I also tried to convert the factor variable `tag` to `character` after or before sorting, but that does not change anything as well. All of these failed attempts have been based on previous answers, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774210/how-do-you-specifically-order-ggplot2-x-axis-instead-of-alphabetical-order). The code provided here was run on https://rdrr.io/snippets/ to make sure it was not the fault of my system. The below image is copied from that run.

[image]

This is certainly a highly frequently asked question, but I have tried my best to follow other answers or search for tutorials without success. So your help will be very much appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

removing `paste0` around `tag` in `aes` solved the problem.
[image]