# How can I rename the variables used for a graph only for that graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I hope this comes as an easy question for some of you.
I am basically plotting the Average Marginal Effects of several variables based on a logistic regression:

```
summary(AMElogmodel1 <- glm(Smartphone ~ sf_group + sf_sex + age + sf_marital + sf_big + sf_hhsize, 
                        data = Selectsfinal, family = binomial(link = "logit"), na.action = na.exclude))
```

And then, in order to have the plot with ggplot instead of the default AME plot for this cases I did this (mainly because I wanted to revert the X and Y axis):

```
xxx <- summary(margins(AMElogmodel1))
ggplot(data = xxx) +
  geom_point(aes(factor, AME)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = factor, ymin = lower, ymax = upper)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x='Variable', y ="Average marginal effect")
```

Leading to this graph:
[image]

As you can see, the names displayed there are the technical names for the variables and their categories. I imagine that if I change their names and labels this would work, but then it would mess with all my other code. Is there a way to change the names? So instead of sf_sexMale, Male and instead of age66-76, Age 66-76?
Also, is there a way to change the order in which they are displayed?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: This should work, try adding   +scale_x_discrete(labels=c("sf_sexMale"="Male", "age66-76"="Age 66-76"))
Although I'm sure there is a more efficient way.

Comment: Thanks, it was that! Any tips on how to change the order in which they are displayed?

Comment: This might offer the solution, it reorders the axis without changing the data 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774210/how-do-you-specifically-order-ggplot2-x-axis-instead-of-alphabetical-order

Comment: @cgvoller Want to paste your solution into an answer, so this question is not flagged as open?