# Stop R from Re-Ordering X-axis Label Using Ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want my `X-axis label to be arranged as it is in the data frame and not re-arranged alphabetically as [image: it is here]

```
df1 <- read.table(text =
                    "nbb_RMSE  9 0.2402482
                    mbb_RMSE  9 0.1023012
                    cbb_RMSE  8 0.2031448
                    tmbb_RMSE 4 0.2654746
                    tcbb_RMSE 9 0.4048711")

colnames(df1) <- c("Methods", "lb", "RMSE")

df1 |>
  dplyr::mutate(colour = fct_reorder(Methods, RMSE)) |>
  ggplot2::ggplot(aes(Methods, RMSE, colour = colour)) + 
  ggplot2::geom_point(size = 4) + 
  ggplot2::geom_segment(aes(Methods, xend = Methods, yend = RMSE, y = 0)) + 
  ggplot2::scale_color_manual(values = c("green", "yellowgreen", "yellow", 
                            "orange", "red"),
                 labels = c(9, 8, 9, 9, 4), name = "lb") + 
  ggplot2::theme_bw(base_size = 16)
```

**What I want**

I want `nbb_RMSE`, `mbb_RMSE`, `cbb_RMSE` `tmbb_RMSE`, `tcbb_RMSE` chronologically in X-axis label.

**Note**

I want its legend to remain as it is (from green to red)

**Edit**

The following answers does not work in my case [Order discrete x scale by frequency/value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253641/order-discrete-x-scale-by-frequency-value) and [How do you specifically order ggplot2 x axis instead of alphabetical order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774210/how-do-you-specifically-order-ggplot2-x-axis-instead-of-alphabetical-order)

Comment: Your suggested solution doesn't work in my case

Comment: I think if you add the line `dplyr::mutate(Methods = fct_inorder(Methods)) |>` you'll have it.

Comment: Yes, it does work