# In R, how can I get geom_line to display a time series in chronological order when time is a factor?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I cannot get `geom_line` to display a time series from oldest to newest when date is a factor.

([Similar SO Question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73407985/in-r-how-can-i-get-geom-boxplot-to-display-a-time-series-in-chronological-order) for `geom_boxplot`.

Example Dataset

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 12))
colnames(df1)[1:3] <- c("Date", "Group", "Value")
df1$Date <- rep(seq.Date(as.Date("2020-03-14"),as.Date("2020-08-20"),"1 month"),2)
df1$Group <- sort(rep(c("A","B"),6))
df1$Value <- rnorm(12,50,20)
df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(Month = month(Date),
         Year = year(Date),
         date = zoo::as.yearmon(paste(Year, Month), "%Y %m"))

df2 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 12))
colnames(df2)[1:3] <- c("Date", "Group", "Value")
df2$Date <- rep(seq.Date(as.Date("2021-03-14"),as.Date("2021-08-20"),"1 month"),2)
df2$Group <- sort(rep(c("A","B"),6))
df2$Value <- rnorm(12,50,20)
df2 <- df2 %>%
  mutate(Month = month(Date),
         Year = year(Date),
         date = zoo::as.yearmon(paste(Year, Month), "%Y %m"))

df3 <- rbind(df1,df2)
```

In this plot, the date is in alphabetical order. I need it to be in chronological order.

```
library(ggplot2)

cols <- c("A" = "#ca0020", "B" = "#0571b0")

ggplot(data = df1, aes(x = factor(date), y = Value, color = Group, group = Group)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(size = 3, aes(fill = Group), color = "black", shape = 21) +
  geom_line(data = df2, aes(x = factor(date), y = Value, color = Group, group = Group)) +
  geom_point(data = df2, aes(x = factor(date), y = Value, fill = Group), color = "black", shape = 21, size = 3) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = cols) +
  scale_color_manual(values = cols) +
  labs(x = "") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        text = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14, color = "black", angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14, color = "black"),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.direction = "horizontal",
        legend.margin = margin(),
        legend.position = c(0.75,0.95))
```

This code works when I look at one year at a time. I know I could display each year with a `facet_wrap()` but I need the data displayed on one figure.

```
ggplot(data = df1, aes(x = factor(date), y = Value, color = Group, group = Group)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(size = 3, aes(fill = Group), color = "black", shape = 21) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = cols) +
  scale_color_manual(values = cols) +
  labs(x = "") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        text = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14, color = "black", angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14, color = "black"),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.direction = "horizontal",
        legend.margin = margin(),
        legend.position = c(0.75,0.95))
```

I have also tried this, but the problem with this one is that the line connecting year `2020` and `2021` should be broken.

```
ggplot(data = df3, aes(x = factor(date), y = Value, color = Group, group = Group)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(size = 3, aes(fill = Group), color = "black", shape = 21) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = cols) +
  scale_color_manual(values = cols) +
  labs(x = "") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
      text = element_text(size = 16),
      axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14, color = "black", angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1),
      axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14, color = "black"),
      legend.title = element_blank(),
      legend.direction = "horizontal",
      legend.margin = margin(),
      legend.position = c(0.75,0.95))
```

The ideal output would look something like this; notice the line connecting data points breaks across years. I am using `x = factor(date)` because I will eventually add an x-axis break which requires the axis to be a factor.
[image]

Comment: For the last graph, instead of ```group = Group```, if you made it ```group = paste(Year,Group)```, it might work.

Comment: @Silentdevildoll that did the trick!