# Order months on the x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, x-axis

I need to create a graph, which should be ordered chronologically according to the column `Variac_2019`.

Nonetheless, I want the x axis to be labelled as the column `Mes1_Any`. The problem is data RStudio is ordering the x axis alphabetically:

[image]

How can I get the x axis labelled as column `Mes1_Any` and ordered as column `Variac_2019`?

My dataset:

```
structure(list(Mes1_Any = c("Gen.2020", "Feb.", "Març", "Abril", 
"Maig", "Juny", "Jul.", "Ag.", "Set.", "Oct.", "Nov.", "Des.", 
"Gen.2021", "Feb.", "Març", "Abril", "Maig", "Juny", "Jul.", 
"Ag.", "Set.", "Oct.", "Nov.", "Des.", "Gen.2022", "Feb.", "Març", 
"Abril", "Maig", "Juny", "Jul.", "Ag.", "Gen.2020", "Feb.", "Març", 
"Abril", "Maig", "Juny", "Jul.", "Ag.", "Set.", "Oct.", "Nov.", 
"Des.", "Gen.2021", "Feb.", "Març", "Abril", "Maig", "Juny", 
"Jul.", "Ag.", "Set.", "Oct.", "Nov.", "Des.", "Gen.2022", "Feb.", 
"Març", "Abril", "Maig", "Juny", "Jul.", "Ag."), Variac_2019 = c("2020_01", 
"2020_02", "2020_03", "2020_04", "2020_05", "2020_06", "2020_07", 
"2020_08", "2020_09", "2020_10", "2020_11", "2020_12", "2021_01", 
"2021_02", "2021_03", "2021_04", "2021_05", "2021_06", "2021_07", 
"2021_08", "2021_09", "2021_10", "2021_11", "2021_12", "2022_01", 
"2022_02", "2022_03", "2022_04", "2022_05", "2022_06", "2022_07", 
"2022_08", "2020_01", "2020_02", "2020_03", "2020_04", "2020_05", 
"2020_06", "2020_07", "2020_08", "2020_09", "2020_10", "2020_11", 
"2020_12", "2021_01", "2021_02", "2021_03", "2021_04", "2021_05", 
"2021_06", "2021_07", "2021_08", "2021_09", "2021_10", "2021_11", 
"2021_12", "2022_01", "2022_02", "2022_03", "2022_04", "2022_05", 
"2022_06", "2022_07", "2022_08"), Territori = c("Catalunya", 
"Catalunya", "Catalunya", "Catalunya", "Catalunya", "Catalunya", 
"Catalunya", "Catalunya", "Catalunya", "Catalunya", "Catalunya", 
"Catalunya", "Catalunya", "Catalunya", "Catalunya", "Catalunya", 
"Catalunya", "Catalunya", "Catalunya", "Catalunya", "Catalunya", 
"Catalunya", "Catalunya", "Catalunya", "Catalunya", "Catalunya", 
"Catalunya", "Catalunya", "Catalunya", "Catalunya", "Catalunya", 
"Catalunya", "Espanya", "Espanya", "Espanya", "Espanya", "Espanya", 
"Espanya", "Espanya", "Espanya", "Espanya", "Espanya", "Espanya", 
"Espanya", "Espanya", "Espanya", "Espanya", "Espanya", "Espanya", 
"Espanya", "Espanya", "Espanya", "Espanya", "Espanya", "Espanya", 
"Espanya", "Espanya", "Espanya", "Espanya", "Espanya", "Espanya", 
"Espanya", "Espanya", "Espanya"), Alimentació = c(-4.76190476190477, 
-4.51745379876797, -0.196850393700776, -15.1950718685832, -20.4007285974499, 
-5.13089005235603, -3.37394564198689, -1.94174757281553, 3.94600207684319, 
-8.44564240790655, -7.68518518518518, 6.2227074235808, -11.175898931001, 
-2.87474332648872, 6.29921259842521, 1.95071868583161, -6.46630236794171, 
9.42408376963351, -0.749765698219307, 6.25674217907228, 15.3686396677051, 
-2.60557053009882, 3.42592592592592, 16.2663755458515, -6.99708454810496, 
1.5400410677618, 9.25196850393701, -1.74537987679672, -0.637522768670318, 
11.0994764397906, -2.43673851921276, 8.62998921251348, -6.66058394160584, 
-5.89410589410588, 0.595829195630571, -11.8181818181818, -18.3970856102004, 
-4.42211055276382, -4.65753424657533, -6.06653620352251, 1.24879923150818, 
-9.30434782608696, -3.59168241965974, 3.06122448979591, -16.514598540146, 
-5.79420579420579, 5.56107249255213, -0.707070707070712, -7.01275045537341, 
7.33668341708542, -2.46575342465754, 0.684931506849318, 9.12584053794427, 
-5.39130434782609, 7.65595463137998, 9.89795918367347, -9.85401459854014, 
-3.4965034965035, 6.05759682224429, -0.202020202020203, -0.637522768670318, 
10.5527638190955, -4.5662100456621, 5.7729941291585)), row.names = c(NA, 
-64L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Current code:

```
plot1 <- ggplot(alimentacio, aes(x=Mes1_Any, y=Alimentació, color= Territori, group=Territori))+
  geom_line()
```

Comment: Post your existing code, and reproducible example data.

Comment: One option would be to convert your column to factor with the order of the levels set in your desired order. See e.g. [How do you specifically order ggplot2 x axis instead of alphabetical order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774210/how-do-you-specifically-order-ggplot2-x-axis-instead-of-alphabetical-order).

Comment: But the problem is that I have quite many levels.

Comment: No, the problem is that your dataset is poorly constructed relative to your objective.  You need either to put the effort in to deal with the poorly constructed data or to put the effort in to convert your dataset to a more convenient form.  Personally, I would covert your character representations of "month/year" to proper dates (you'll have to impute a day value, but that's not an issue) and then use that as your x-axis column.  Also, note that your sample data is incrrectly formatted [Corrected by edit.].

Comment: The reason your dataset is poorly constructed is that it contains no information about the ordering of values in `Mes1_Any` by time and this is *precisely* the information you need to construct the graph that you want.

Comment: Okey thank you. I already have a new column in my dataset with proper dates. But how can I use column `Mes1_Any` to label the x axis?

Comment: Well thank you. At the end I converted `Mes1_Any` into a factor variable setting its levels as unique: `alimentacio$Mes1_Any<- factor(alimentacio$Mes1_Any, levels=unique(alimentacio$Mes1_Any))`

Comment: `Me1_Any` is already being used to label the x axis in your image and code. It just doesn't contain the values OR labels (two different things) that you want. Either create an actual date variable (https://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html) or turn the variable into a factor and order it appropriately as desired.

Comment: Hint: instead of those month abbreviations, use `m<- as.Date(paste(2021, 1:12, 1, sep = "-")); abb <- format(m, "%b")`. This gives 3 letters month names in your locale. Then, convert to factor with those levels.

Answer (score 0):

You can use convert `Variac_2019` into a date using `lubridate::ym()`, then convert `Mes1_Any` into an ordered factor whose levels are based on the order of those dates.

```r
require(lubridate)
require(ggplot2)
require(forcats)
require(dplyr)

## Convert Variac_2019 into data using `lubridate::ym()`
alimentacio <- mutate(alimentacio, Variac_2019 = lubridate::ym(Variac_2019))

## Convert Mes1Any into ordered factor with
## levels based on Variac_2019
alimentacio <- mutate(alimentacio,
                      Mes1_Any =
                        forcats::fct_reorder(Mes1_Any, Variac_2019) |> 
                        ordered()) # convert to ordered factor

ggplot(alimentacio,
       aes(x = Mes1_Any, y = Alimentació,
           color = Territori, group = Territori)
       ) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>