# How can I re-label and re-arrange the sub-sections of my violin plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a violin plot in R for publication.  The code right now is pretty basic:

```
ggplot(data=kilim_wider,aes(x=date_by_fd,y=fd_overall))+
  geom_violin()+theme_classic()+
  labs(x="Date determined by fiber diameter",y="Average fiber diameter (µm)",title="Fiber diameter distribution per time period")
```

With the following result

[out of order plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpTGi.png)

I'd like to do two things:

1. Because these are date ranges, I want them in chronological order.  Is there a way that I can specify that I want 18th C first, then early-19th C, then mid-19th..... etc?
2. Change the individual plot labels from "18th_c" "early_19th_c" to "18th Century" "Early 19th Century"

The dataset kilim_wider is huge, but here's a subset of what I'm currently working with

| date_by_fd | fd_overall |
| --- | --- |
| mid_19th_c | 43.77 |
| mid_19th_c | 42.55 |
| 18th_c | 49.22 |
| early_19th_c | 47.21 |
| 20th_c | 35.5 |

I tried using `scale_fill_discrete()` to change the labels, but that just gave an error.  The R Graph Gallery has no suggestions for how to do either of these things.

Comment: Your are looking for `factor` and arguments `levels` and `lables`, like: `kilim_wider %>% 
  mutate(date_by_fd = factor(date_by_fd, levels = c("18th_c", "early_19th_c", "mid_19th_c", "20th_c"), 
                             labels = c("18th Century",  "Early 19th Century", "mid_19th_c", "20th_c"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=date_by_fd,y=fd_overall))+
  geom_violin()+theme_classic()+
  labs(x="Date determined by fiber diameter",y="Average fiber diameter (µm)",title="Fiber diameter distribution per time period")`

Comment: As you dealing with the x axis try with `scale_x_discrete`. To set the order you can use `limits=` and for the labels use `labels=`. See e.g.[How do you specifically order ggplot2 x axis instead of alphabetical order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774210/how-do-you-specifically-order-ggplot2-x-axis-instead-of-alphabetical-order)

Comment: There are 2 common way to order a discrete axis. My usual favorite is to encode the ordering in the data itself by making the column a `factor` with the levels specified in the desired order: `kilim_wider$date_by_fd = factor(kilim_wider$date_by_fd, levels = c("18th_c", "early_19th_c"))`. You can add a `labels` argument to re-label it to your desired labels in this step as well, add `labels = c("18th Century", "Early 19th Century", ...)` as argument to the same `factor` call.

Comment: The second way is to use `scale_x_discrete`, where you can use `limits` to define the order of the axis values and `labels` to re-label them. This will not change your data, it will affect only the one plot. You can see examples of this at the bottom of the `?scale_x_discrete` help page or at the marked duplicate. In your case, `+ scale_x_discrete(limits = c("18th_c", "early_19th_c"), labels = c("18th Century", "Early 19th Century"))`