I want to be able to give a certain value in a column of strings by a column of int in r

I have this data frame with the value I want to take to the graph which is the_bin and the value where I want them to be arranged which is the_bin_num but.
And I get something:

You can see that they are not arranged at all
I would be happy for ideas
ggplot(data = data_by_time2,aes(x=the_bin,y=avg,fill =avg))+geom_bar(stat = "identity",position = "dodge")+
  labs(title = "Average Profit According To The Running Time Of The Movie",x="Run Time",y="Mean Trim Profit",color="Mean Trim Profit",fill="Mean Trim")+
  facet_grid(.~genres)+theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,vjust = 0.5 ,hjust = 1))


Please do not provide your data as an image.  No one wants to type it all in again to test code.  Instead, please use dput to make a text version of your data that we can simply cut and paste.

They are arranged in order, but the order is alphabetical because they are text strings. There are many, many posts on this site explaining that to correctly order text strings in ggplot one must convert to a factor and specify the order

See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774210/how-do-you-specifically-order-ggplot2-x-axis-instead-of-alphabetical-order

I had a similar problem with a very simple solution: forcats::fct_inorder()
The function fct_inorder() uses the current table order to order the resulting factor.
data_by_time2 %>%
  arrange(the_bin) %>%
  ggplot(data = data_by_time2,aes(x=forcats::fct_inorder(the_bin),y=avg,fill =avg))

